# Overloading a function in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am developing a simulation in NetLogo that will ultimately have multiple permutations. In the end, I'll have `Sim1.nlogo`, `Sim2.nlogo`, `Sim3.nlogo`, et cetera all including `libsim.nls`.

What I'd like to know is, if I have a function in `libsim.nls` that is identical in all but one of my models, can I overload it in the model that differs, or will I have to duplicate the code manually in each permutation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact thing you're asking for isn't possible. But you don't need to duplicate code in all of the models, either.

I'd suggest the following approach. In `libsim.nls`, give the standard implementation a standard name like `foo-standard`.  Then in `Sim1.nlogo` and `Sim2.nlogo` you can have the one-liner `to foo foo-standard end`, and in Sim3.nlogo you can have `to foo ... end` with a different body, that doesn't call the "standard" implementation.